# Bypassing error in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

While inserting multiple rows into a table in SQL Server, if a get an error, how can I just log that error and move on to insert the next record by bypassing that error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't when all the insert run in one go (like in a `insert into ... select`. A database implements ACID, and one of the components (A, Atomicy) means (according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID#Atomicity)):

> Atomicity requires that each transaction is "all or nothing"

That means that you have to separate your action in single statements, which in SQL Server are single transactions (in Oracle on the other hand, this won't still work since it runs all subsequent queries in one transaction by default).

You can although create separate insert statements and put every statement in a [`try catch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx).

Sample:

```
-- first
begin try
    insert into ...
end try
begin catch
    -- log error
end catch; 

-- second
begin try
    insert into ...
end try
begin catch
    -- log error
end catch;
```

Comment: Thanks Patrick but I heard and tried adding a GO after the insert it actually inserts the next record. For that matter updates will be successful as well..Also can you tell me in which table logs are stored or how can I manually store the logs?

Comment: I don't know if there is a default log location where this type of errors are saved (I don't think so). There is an option for [audit logs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280728.aspx), but this is probably not what you want. You can use a `try ... catch`, and on error, you can insert in a logging table yourself.

Comment: Thanks.But using 'go' just displays the error and moves on to enter the next record. It doesn't stop. How's that?

Comment: I think that works in SQL Server Management Studio, but not when calling from external code.